# Zoom to extent using geom or xmax, ymax?

Tags: polygon, openlayers, geometry, zoom

I made a function to zoom to polygon geom if I click the button. This is my script:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'core/zoomtolocation',
            data: {
                iddesa: iddesa,
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (responsezoom) {
                if (responsezoom!='kosong') {

                    $.each(responsezoom, function (index, value) { 

                        var extent = [value.geom];
                        map.getView().fitExtent(extent,map.getSize())

                        // var maxExtent = [parseFloat(value.xmax), parseFloat(value.ymax), parseFloat(value.xmin), parseFloat(value.ymin)];
                        // map.getView().fit(maxExtent, { duration: 1000 });
                    });

                } else {

                }
            }
        });
```

But from that script I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: map.getView is not a function.

I'm using OpenLayers 4.

Comment: There is no `.fitExtent()` method, `.fit()` is used for both geometry and extents.  An extent is defined as `[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]`.  An OpenLayers geometry is passed directly, not inside an array.